# best way to copy all files from Amazon S3 bucket to a Microsoft Azure Container

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, migration, backup

I need to copy ( for backup purpose ) all the files ( like 100.000+ video files ) from an Amazon S3 bucket to an empty Azure Blob container.
We are not migrating from Amazon to Azure but we want a backup, just in case...

Which is the fastest way to do it?

I read that Azure is able to download the files itself from the Amazon S3 without passing for a local machine. That will be great because we will save lots of bandwidth and time...

I also read about this project:
https://github.com/kpfaulkner/azurecopy
But I don't have a computer with Windows OS at the moment ( if I have to I will consider to setup a virtual machine with it ).
Is there a way to do it with a MAC?
or from bash Command line?  Or in PHP?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have a Java 8 program laying around for this...

This project will be built in Netbeans 8.0.1 using Java 8. First we will create a new Maven Java Application. Maven will be used to import the AWS and Azure SDKs.

[image]

Name your project AWStoAzure, and replace mycompany with your typically package system.

[image]

Open Pom.xml and the pom given below.

The key steps to my program involve more of Amazon SDK features then Azure SDK. Using the Amazon SDK I first connect to my Amazon account using the provided public and private keys.

[image]

Next, I retrieve a list of all files located in a given bucket, and retrieve the metadata for each file.

[image]

I then use Java 8’s new streaming feature to launch multiple threads each responsible for connecting to Azure and initiating a file transfer process.

[image]

Azure offers as part of the SDK the service to provide an http(s) url and load the data from that URL into your blob. This SDK feature is what puts most of the workload on Azure, and allows my tool to not have to remain connecting to any cloud service while the data is being loaded into the blob.

[image]

Amazon S3 using a folder like naming convention, but blob storage does not have this, so I create contains for each folder that was in S3.

[image]

Amazon’s SDK offers the ability to generate a URL that has the username and password for the account embed in it. This allows us to expose our files to Azure, but not having to worry about the files being open to the public internet.

[image]

Including the POM file I used.

Java Source

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.microsoft.azure.aws;

import com.amazonaws.HttpMethod;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GeneratePresignedUrlRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.OperationContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Dan
 */
public class AzuretoAWSDriver {

    private static String connectionString = "";

    public static void run(String accessKey, String secretKey, String bucketName) {

        AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));

        amazonS3Client.listObjects(bucketName)
                .getObjectSummaries()
                .stream()
                .forEach(s3ObjectSummary
                        -> S3toBlob(amazonS3Client, s3ObjectSummary));
    }

    public static void S3toBlob(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary) {
        try {
            String[] split = s3ObjectSummary.getKey().split("/");
            GetContainer(s3ObjectSummary)
                    .getBlockBlobReference(split[split.length - 1])
                    .startCopyFromBlob(GetURL(amazonS3Client, s3ObjectSummary), null, null, null, new OperationContext());
        } catch (URISyntaxException | StorageException | InvalidKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AzuretoAWSDriver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    private static CloudBlobContainer GetContainer(S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary) throws URISyntaxException, InvalidKeyException, StorageException {
        String[] split = s3ObjectSummary.getKey().split("/");
        String folders = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length - 2; i++) {
            folders += split[i];
        }
        CloudBlobContainer containerReference = CloudStorageAccount
                .parse(connectionString)
                .createCloudBlobClient()
                .getContainerReference(s3ObjectSummary.getBucketName() + folders);
        containerReference.createIfNotExists();
        return containerReference;
    }

    private static URI GetURL(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary) throws URISyntaxException {
        return amazonS3Client.generatePresignedUrl(
                new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(s3ObjectSummary.getBucketName(), s3ObjectSummary.getKey())
                .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                .withExpiration(GetExperation())).toURI();
    }

    private static Date GetExperation() {                     
        return new Date((new Date().getTime()) + 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
  <artifactId>AWStoAzure2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>AWS SDK for Java Sample</name>
  <url>http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>[1.7.2,2.0.0)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
     <groupId>com.microsoft.windowsazure.storage</groupId>
     <artifactId>microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>AwsSdkSample</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score -2):

There are tools available that can do what you want to do. Google for `Cloud Data Migration`.

Another thing you may need to think about is incremental copying. For example, when you start the copy task for the 2nd time, you would not want to copy all objects again, and only need to add/update/delete objects.

Comment: Please be careful with linking to a third-party site, someone may think this is a spam post and flag, delete it. [Don't be a **spammer**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Kevin! I do work for this company, but thought that my answer will be helpful. Don't want to spam or break any rules.

Comment: Yeah, I think you don't :).